# Using ModelFormMixin without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.11

I'm using Django 1.11

I have created a `Form` and using `Class based view` to create a record and save to database.

**Business/models.py**

```
class BusinessType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField('last modified', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'business_types'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Business(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    business_type = models.ForeignKey(BusinessType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField('last modified', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'business'
        verbose_name_plural = 'businesses'
        db_table = 'businesses'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Business/Forms.py**

```
class BusinessForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ['user']
```

**Business/views.py**

```
class BusinessCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Business
    form = BusinessForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, 'form is valid')
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Business Added Successfully')
        return reverse('business:list')
```

On loading template of `BusinessCreate` it gives error as

**Using ModelFormMixin (base class of BusinessCreate) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.**

***My Trials***

After moving `fields` to `views class`, it is working fine. But I don't want to do so, as I may be using this form on multiple views and thus will require changes on multiple pages in future if needed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your form is not being recognised. This is because you have used `form` to set the attribute in the view, but the correct attribute is `form_class`.

(Note, if you correctly set `form_class`, you don't need `model` as well.)

Comment: Thanks @daniel, I was stuck with this error from last one week

Comment: can you help a bit more as `def get_success_url` is not calling after saving record to database. and it is giving error as `The view business.views.BusinessCreate didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: `get_success_url` is called by the default implementation of `form_valid`, which you have overridden. You need to return the redirect from that method, for example `return redirect(self.get_success_url())`. Note that the `messages.success` call shouldn't really be in that method.

Answer (score 13):

for me it is fixed by adding fields variable like this

`model = xxxxxxxxxx
fields = '__all__'`

after model name

refer to this [url](https://itbinnacle.wordpress.com/2015/12/27/django-using-modelformmixin-base-class-of-createuserview-without-the-fields-attribute-is-prohibited/)